# Android Image Viewer from App

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to launch an image which is written to my application directory with the builtin Android image viewer. This image has been written in a different part of the app to the app directory. When getting the following file:

`super.getFilesDir() + "/current.png"`

File.exists() returns true.

How can i launch the builtin Android image viewer to view this file?
Currently i'm doing:

```
File f = new File(super.getFilesDir()+"/current.png");
uri = Uri.parse("file://"+super.getFilesDir()+"/current.png");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

And it keeps churning out:

> 10-11 13:09:24.367:
>   INFO/ActivityManager(564): Starting
>   activity: Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=file:///data/data/com.davidgoemans.myapp/files/current.png
>   } 10-11 13:09:24.367:
>   ERROR/myapp(2166): Exception
>   occuredandroid.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
>   No Activity found to handle Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=file:///data/data/com.davidgoemans.myapp/files/current.png
>   }

irrespective of what i change the uri schema to ( eg, content://, file://, media://, image:// ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to implement a context provider to give other applications access to your data.

Create a new class containing:

```
public class FileContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
   private static final String URI_PREFIX = "content://uk.co.ashtonbrsc.examplefilecontentprovider";

   public static String constructUri(String url) {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
       return uri.isAbsolute() ? url : URI_PREFIX + url;
   }

   @Override
   public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
       File file = new File(uri.getPath());
       ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
       return parcel;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreate() {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] as) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

   @Override
   public String getType(Uri uri) {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

   @Override
   public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

   @Override
   public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] as, String s, String[] as1, String s1) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

   @Override
   public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues, String s, String[] as) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

}
```

Add the content provider to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider android:name=".FileContentProvider" android:authorities="uk.co.ashtonbrsc.examplefilecontentprovider" />
```

You should then be able to use `"content://uk.co.ashtonbrsc.examplefilecontentprovider/" + the full path to the image` in your ACTION_VIEW intent.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out tonight. I pretty much had that implemented, it just seems like such overkill to execute an application. Great design/architecture, but over complex for basic usage.

Comment: Note: Overriding getType() required me to set the mime type, eg:
   @Override
   public String getType(Uri uri) 
   {
    return "image/png";
   }

Comment: This is working well for me in my application, thanks to both of you, ... I was surprised how few apps can consume my intent though.  Is Intent.ACTION_VIEW the wrong choice?  Should I pick a mime type other than image/jpg?

Answer (score 3):

Option #1: Create a `ContentProvider` to serve up the file out of your app's private file area, then use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on that `content://` `Uri`.

Option #2: Move the file to the SD card, and use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on the `Uri` and also with the appropriate MIME type. Android does not automatically associate file extensions with MIME types, so you need to tell the `Intent` what sort of MIME type the `Uri` points to. This is handled for you "automatically" with the `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Part of the problem is that i'm stuggling to find firm examples of how to server up my app's private file area with a Content Provider or how to use a custom dir on the SD Card to server my files. The Android documentation very vaguely describes the Content Provider procedure, and copy/pasting their XML doesn't build.

Answer (score 3):

Your image is within your application sandbox, so you should use `ContentProvider` to give other apps external access to your image data. Keep in mind that in Android, pre-installed apps don't have higher priority than third-party apps - you still have to give permission to your data, even if you want to use the default apps.

Otherwise, take a look at the Gallery activity's `IntentFilter` tags in the Camera application, for a reference what `Intent` you can use to open an image with the default viewer.