# webview image enlarge on click android

Tags: android, image, webview

I have an image in a webview, when the user clicks it I want it to open up in the full screen. How do I accomplish this?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29), capture the image url when the user clicks on the image. Then use [Android Image Viewer from App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550657/android-image-viewer-from-app) to show the image (after downloading it from the captured url).